# Android Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` to display my **products**, problem is when if I select the first products and scroll down to the end of list I see different products selected and when i scroll back to top of list the first item is not selected.

> **My Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

String u = "http://192.185.52.231/~sabby070/hyype/";
Context context1;
private java.util.List<ProductDetails> List;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

public RecyclerAdapter(List<ProductDetails> DataList, FragmentActivity activity) {
    this.List = DataList;
    context1 = activity;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView Likecount;
    public ImageView Image;
    public ImageView Imagelike, ImageUnlike;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        Likecount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemPrice);
        Image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_imgtosold);
        Imagelike = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Like_Button);
        ImageUnlike = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.UnLike_Button);

    }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ProductDetails detail = List.get(position);
    holder.Likecount.setText(detail.getLikeCount());
    Glide.with(context1).load(u+detail.getImage()).override(600, 200).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.Image);
    holder.Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context1, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context1, Buy_Product.class);
            intent.putExtra("Product Name",detail.getLikeCount());
            intent.putExtra("Product Image",detail.getImage());
            context1.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    holder.Imagelike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.Imagelike.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            {
                holder.Imagelike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ImageUnlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

holder.ImageUnlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (holder.ImageUnlike.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        {
            holder.Imagelike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.ImageUnlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return List.size();
}

}
```

> My class

```
public class Men_Fragment extends Fragment {

static String URL = "http://192.185.52.231/~sabby070/hyype/index.php?action=timeline&user_id=53&post_category=timeline";
private List<ProductDetails> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter rAdapter;
String img;
String a;
Boolean list[];


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_men_, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.men_recycler_view);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));

                    a = obj.getString("like_count");
                    img = obj.getString("video_thumb");

                    final ProductDetails details = new ProductDetails(a, img);
                    DataList.add(details);

                    rAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(DataList, getActivity());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: How are you keeping track of selected row?

Comment: well use a web service the functionality or use the sqlite

Comment: You can use a library called drag-select-recyclerview find it here https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You have to take List(with boolean) and store selected values in that list and then use those values in onBindView()

Answer (score 0):

In your ProductDetails class add a field `boolean selected;`

In your `onClick()` add `List.get(position).setSelected(!List.get(position).isSelected());` to check/uncheck as needed.

Finaly in your onBindViewHolder(...) add

```
if(List.get(position).isSelected()){
    holder.Imagelike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    holder.ImageUnlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```